# What is the reason for printing the second value prior to the first value in printf statement?

Tags: c

The following code:

```
void main
{
    int b=10;
    int a=5;
    printf("%d",(b,a));
}
```

This gives an output 5 on execution. Can anyone explain the reason for it?

I expected an output 10 since that is the first value that matches `"%d"`.

Comment: Why are you doing weird things?

Comment: Why do you speak of "match" ?

Comment: It seems this is a late homework due on Monday?

Comment: And your code does not compile. Your `main` is not a function (lack of formal arguments, and should return `int`)

Answer (score 3):

Read about the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). Your `(b,a)` expression is evaluated to 5 (the value of `a`).

<sup>Also, take the good habit of ending your `printf` format control strings with a newline `\n` or else call sometimes `fflush` (which gets automatically called after `main`, using `atexit` techniques). Remember that `<stdio.h>` streams are buffered!</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In C, `(b,a)` means "calculate b, then calculate and return a". So, It's practically the same as just `a` in your case.